# how to bind more than one model with single view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Guys I have tried to use more than one Models with single view.

but I could not found the solution how to implement it.

I want to use One View data in Single past and the other in another part..

I have used the following code..

this is one view

```
@Html.Partial("Sidebar")
```

this is another view

```
    <!-- start content -->
    <div id="content">
        <div class="post">
            <h1 class="title">
                Add New Post
            </h1>

<p></p>
            <div class="entry">
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    <div>
                        <div style="display:inline;">
                            <div style="display: inline; float: left;">
                                @Html.Label("lblcategory", "Category", new { style = "Width:100px; float: left;" })
                                <div style="width: 150px; height: 60px; overflow-y: scroll; display: inline; float: left;">
                                    @for (int i = 0; i < (int)TempData["Rows"]; i++)
                                    {
                                        for (int j = 0; j < (int)TempData["Cols"]; j++)
                                        {
                                            <input id="Checkbox + @i" name = "Category" type="checkbox" style="width:50px;" value="@TempData["[" + i.ToString() + "][" + j.ToString() + "]"]"/>
                                            @TempData["[" + i.ToString() + "][" + j.ToString() + "]"]
                                        }
                                    }                                   
                                    @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryName)*@
                                </div>
                                <div style="float:right;">
                                    <label id="lblcategoryrequired" style="color:Red">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryName)</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p style="display: inline; float: left;">
                                @Html.Label("lblsubjet", "Subject", new { style = "Width:100px; float: left;" })
                                @*@Html.TextBox("txtsubject", "", new { style = "Width:700px;" })*@
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PostSubject, new { style = "Width:400px; maxlength=400;" })
                                <label id="lblsubjectrequired" style="color:Red">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostSubject)</label>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p style="display: inline; float: left;">
                                @Html.Label("lblcontent", "Content", new { style = "Width:100px; float: left; Vertical-align:top;" })
                                @*@Html.TextArea("txtcontent","", new { style = "Width:700px; height:200px; maxlength=700;" })*@
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PostContent, new { style = "Width:400px; height:200px; maxlength=400;" })
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p style="display: inline; float: left;">
                                @Html.Label("lblblank", "a", new { style = "Width:100px; float: left; Color:#372412" })
                                <input type="submit" value="Add" id="btnadd" style="width: 100px;" class="button" />
                                &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                                <a id="Cancel" href="~/Home/Home"> <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btncancel" class="button" style="width: 100px;" /></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can have a viewmodel that has both models and you can bind that with your view

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question 100%. But if I were to understand it then I don't think it will work the way that you need it to work (I might be mistaken). I would suggest that you move away from your partial view and just pass in one `view model` that you can use to populate both sections. View models are there to represent your data on a view.

I'm going to give you a basic sample that you can modify and use in your scenario. Lets say we have a customer and this customer can have 1 or many addresses. So a basic representation of these 2 models could look like this:

```
public class Customer
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     public string LastName { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

     public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

     public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
}
```

And now on your details view you want to display the customer's details and the addresses of this customer. So we have 2 models (customer and address) that you are displaying on 1 view.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
     Customer customer = customerRepository.GetById(id);

     if (customer != null)
     {
          customer.Addresses = addressRepository.GetAddressesForCustomer(customer.Id);
     }

     // The above 2 steps can be done in 1 repository call

     // Now populate your view model with the above details
     // This can also be 1 or 2 lines when you use something like Auto Mapper

     CustomerDetailsViewModel viewModel = new CustomerDetailsViewModel
     {
          viewModel.CustomerId = customer.Id,
          viewModel.CustomerFirstName = customer.FirstName,
          viewModel.CustomerLastName = customer.LastName,
          viewModel.CustomerAddresses = customer.Addresses
     };

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

Your view model:

```
public class CustomerDetailsViewModel
{
     public int CustomerId { get; set; }

     public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }

     public string CustomerLastName { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<Address> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

So now you have 1 view model populated from 2 different models. Now all that you have to do on your view is to use this view model to display data:

```
@model YourProject.ViewModels.Customers.CustomerDetailsViewModel

@Model.CustomerId<br />
@Model.CustomerFirstName<br />
@Model.CustomerLastName<br /><br />

@foreach (var address in @Model.CustomerAddresses)
{
     <div>
          @address.Id<br />
          @address.AddressLine1<br />
          @address.AddressLine2<br />
          @address.AddressLine3<br />
     </div>
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Brendan.. It will definitely help me... Now i got the actual idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a view model that represents the data required to render your view. You could either expose the models directly on the view model (violating [LoD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)), or delegate the calls to the view model to the underlying models (violating the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle).

Comment: Ya dude, I have used the model as @model BloginMVC.Models.PostModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddPost";
    Layout = "~/Views/MasterView/MasterLayout.cshtml";
} but it doesn't go to refer the GET method of the PartialView i.e.Sidebar...

Comment: "it doesn't go to refer the GET method" - I don't know what you mean by this. If you wish to pass a model down to the partial, then you can use e.g. @Html.Partial("Sidebar", model.SidebarModel). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402926(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: I just want to say that I am using One View for displaying data in two parts. In Left I want to display data from PartialView in which i have used 1 model & in other section I want to display data from the sameview in which I have used another Model but the problem is that when the View is loaded it calls the ActionResult Method of type GET of the View but when it Renders PartialView it doesnt call ActionResult Method of GET type of Partialview and gives error like Object reference not set to an instance of an object for MODEL that i have used in Partial View.

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear, but have a look at RenderAction - http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx